# Why is my LEFT JOIN an invalid operation (MS ACCESS 2003)

Tags: ms-access, left-join, ms-access-2003, invalidoperationexception

I have a query which looks very much like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.aNumber = t2.aNumber;
```

When I try to run it, I get `Invalid Operation`. Both of the following queries run fine though:

```
SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

So I'm guessing either the problem is really obvious or really complicated... How can I find the problem in this situation?

---

For completeness, here is the actual query (Query25) and all the other queries it refers to:

**Query25**

```
SELECT *
FROM [EXPORT PRICE AND Desc] LEFT JOIN Export_Union_active ON [EXPORT PRICE AND Desc].MaterialNumber = Export_Union_active.MaterialNumber;
```

**EXPORT PRICE AND Desc**

```
SELECT tblMMMaterials.MaterialNumber, tblMMMaterials.MaterialDescription AS name, Format(tblMMMaterials!SellingPrice,"Standard") AS SellingPrice, dbo_tblMMImages.Notes, tblMMMaterials.MFG, tblMMMaterials.Internet
FROM tblMMMaterials LEFT JOIN dbo_tblMMImages ON tblMMMaterials.MaterialID = dbo_tblMMImages.MaterialID
WHERE (((tblMMMaterials.Internet)=True));
```

**Export_Union_active**

```
select * from Export_Active  UNION ALL select  * from Export_Inactive;
```

**Export_Active**

```
SELECT tblMMMaterials.MaterialNumber, tblMMMaterials.Discontinued, 1 AS [check], tblMMMaterials.MFG
FROM tblMMMaterials
WHERE (((tblMMMaterials.Discontinued)=0) AND ((tblMMMaterials.MFG)="kheops"));
```

**Export_Inactive**

```
SELECT tblMMMaterials.MaterialNumber, tblMMMaterials.Discontinued, 0 AS [check], tblMMMaterials.MFG
FROM tblMMMaterials
WHERE (((tblMMMaterials.Discontinued)=1) AND ((tblMMMaterials.MFG)="kheops"));
```

And here are the tables refered to by all these queries (they are much bigger than this, but I trimmed out anything not used in any of the queries):

**tblMMMaterials**

```
MaterialID          | Number   | PK
MaterialNumber      | Text
MaterialDescription | Text
SellingPrice        | Currency
MFG                 | Text
Internet            | Yes/No
Discontinued        | Yes/No
```

**tblMMImages**

```
ImageID    | AutoNumer | PK
MaterialID | Number
Notes      | Memo
```

Comment: data types? Please post your table schema...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Of course :) I also added queries as text rather than images...